# can't capture PID from background process started in a sub-shell that's running in a heredoc passed to `sudo su`

Tags: bash, process, background-process, subshell

I'm trying to capture the PID of a process started in a sub-shell so I can check if the process started correctly, the process in question is a puma app.

```
sudo su - $APPUSER <<-BASH
    PID="\$(bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb)"

    "\$(bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb & export PID=$1)"

    "\$(bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb &)"

    PID="\$(ps aux | grep \"[p]uma.*[u]nix.*$APPNAME\" | awk '{ print \$2}')"
BASH
```

and it returns nothing, weirdly, if I do any of those without a surrounding `""` I get this error:

```
-bash: line 22: [26740]: command not found
```

the number in the `[]` is the pid, I know this because I get this when I run the script again (I check if the pid exists):

```
app is running with pid: 26740
```

I think this is happening because I'm doing the commands in a heredoc and passing them to `sudo su`

How do I get the pid from the background process I started in a sub-shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't overwrite internal `PID` value. Use lowercase environment variables.

Comment: I didn't realise I was doing that, thank you!